# Getting the User from an APIClient() in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a fixture in pytest that returns a client that has been logged in:

```
@pytest.fixture 
def create_client(create_user) -> APIClient:
    data = {
        "email": create_user.email,
        "password": "TestPassword",
    }
    client = APIClient()
    client.post(path="/user/login/", data=data)
    return client
```

How I get the user that has been logged in in the test?

I understand that I might be able to use a get a request from the client and get it that way:

```
def test_get_user(create_client):
    response = create_client.get(path="/some/random/path/")
    user = response.user
    return user
```

but is there a better way to  do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that the ***`create_user`*** is another *fixture* and thus you can have that in your ***`test_get_user(...)`*** as

```
def test_get_user(create_client, create_user):
    print(create_user)
    # do some tests here
```

Comment: Im still a little unsure of how fixtures work, if the `create_user` fixture is called twice in the same test, once in `create_client` and once in the `test_get_user` then will the code in `create_user` be run twice?